# Чи є відповідник до слова "siblings"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

*Siblings* (з англ.) — кожний з двох або більше дітей, що мають одного або двох спільних батьків (*"each of two or more children or offspring having one or both parents in common"*); брат чи сестра.

Гугл перекладач дає варіанти "брати і сестри", "рідний брат", "рідна сестра", однак цікавить, чи є в українській мові іменник, який був би хорошим відповідником до цього слова (на кшталт слова "[батьки](http://sum.in.ua/s/batjky)", яке позначає і маму, і тата). Крім того, зустрічав я німецький відповідник даного слова — *"Geschwister"*, а також в онлайн-словнику [Глобс](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/sibling) я знайшов варіант *"суродженці"*, однак даного слова немає в СУМі, тому я не впевнений, що його можна вживати.

Comment: Ну, строго кажучи, в українській мові [є рідковживане слово _сиблінг_](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=сиблінг). Дехто [пропонує](//slovotvir.org.ua/words/sybling) _суродженець_ чи _суродженик_, і вони навіть потрапили у [Вікіпедію](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Суродженці) й [інші роботи](http://enpuir.npu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/16369/1/zbirnyk_2017%2B.pdf), але в книжках я їх не бачив. Тобто _сиблінг_ — майже варваризм, але в літературі за потреби регулярно [вживається](//scholar.google.com.ua/scholar?q=%22сиблінг%22), а _суродженець_ — по-моєму, непогана ідея, але поки що майже ніде.

Comment: Якщо сказати *їх діти* стосовно подружжя, то автоматично більшість порахує усіх *siblings*. Потім стануть розбиратися, які *спільні діти*, а які *її/його діти*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Історично, в українській мові відсутнє таке слово.

Для того, щоб знайти найближчий відповідник, варто звернутися до **словників медичних термінів**, і там таке слово є:

> [**Сібси**](http://medterms.com.ua/publ/medichni_termini_na_literu_s/sibsi/20-1-0-622) (від англ. *Siblings, sibs* — брат або сестра) — генетичний термін, що позначає нащадків одних батьків. Рідні брати і сестри, але не близнюки. У тварин - нащадки одних і тих же батьків від різних приплодів.
>   […] Термін вживається, головним чином, у генетиці людини і генетиці тварин.

Ймовірно, **етимологія** цього слова — просте вкорочення літературного англійського слова *sibling*.

Термін зустрічається у виданнях:

- В.Е.Маркевич - Медична генетика. Навчально-методичний посібник для студентів ВНЗ ([посилання](http://elkniga.info/book_124_glava_90_TERM%D0%86NOLOG%D0%86CHNIJJ_SLOVNIK.html));
- Асанов А. Ю. — Основи генетики і спадкові порушення розвитку у дітей, 2003 ([посилання](http://medbib.in.ua/terminologicheskiy-slovar26262.html));
- Медична біологія — Тлумачний словник біологічних термінів і понять ([посилання](https://subject.com.ua/biology/medical/312.html)) — зауважте, тут це слово має форму «**сибси**»;

Позитивною рисою цього слова є ґендерна нейтральність, що відповідає сучасним суспільно-політичним настроям.

Вочевидь, **сфера застосування** цього відповідника обмежена лише умовами, коли контекст припускає використання формального медичного терміну. Наприклад, при перекладі гумористичних матеріалів я б не став використовувати це слово.